# How to more efficiently write a collection to a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a larger code that extracts 250 cells worth of data in one sheet of a workbook (cells are scattered all over the sheet and I need them in a table) and adds it into a collection, to then be written to a single row on a worksheet in another workbook. This code is part of a loop that loops anywhere from 5 to 100 times. The entire code runs rather quickly when looping 5 times but gets bogged down or sometimes even freezes when it loops up to 100 times. In doing some debugging, I found that the speed/freezing issues are entirely isolated to the part of the code that loops through each item in the collection and writes it to the worksheet. Is there a more efficient way to write the collection to the worksheet than what I'm using? Should I transfer the collection to an array then transfer it to the sheet? I've pasted the relevant part of the code below as the whole thing is long but can paste the entire thing on request (not sure it'd help though). I do have the usual code speeding up tricks in place (Application.ScreenUpdating = False, Application.Calculation = xlManual, etc.) already. [note for clarity: colOutput is a Collection and wsOutput is a Sheet, j = the first empty row on the sheet, i is just a counter to iterate through all 250 items in the collection]

```
For i = 1 To colOutput.Count
    wsOutput.Cells(j, i) = colOutput(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Use an array instead. You can dump a 2D variant array onto a worksheet with a single, essentially-instantaneous operation.

Comment: See [VBA Arrays And Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: Thank you both, I'm having much more success writing the collection to an array, then writing that array to the sheet. Cuts way down on the # of times the sheet is accessed (5 to 100 times rather than 1250 to 25000 times)